# Creating a php contact form

Tags: html

I'm currently stuck with this contact form that ends up returning saying form empty.

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
<p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
<p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
<p>Phone</p> <input type="text" name="phone">

<p>Request Phone Call:</p>
Yes:<input type="radio" value="Yes" name="call"><br />
No:<input type="radio" value="No" name="call"><br />

<p>Date</p> <input type="date" name="date">

<p>Venue</p>
<input type="text" name="venue" >

<br />

<p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: All you show HTML form. It will *execute* and will be shown on-screen. What is the problem?

Comment: Return where? Server?

Comment: Once the form is duly filled, it won't execute and send the email to the specified email account

Comment: If you want to send mail using php, read http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

you just posted a html snippet; no php code given in the question.

you find plenty of examples for that, e.g. http://codechirps.com/php-email-contact-form-tutorial/ also like pointed out in comment you will easily find help for the functions (e.g. [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) on php.net).